# Integrate Symfony2 with Hangout service

Tags: php, symfony, google-api, google-hangouts

Are there any chance to integrate a symfony2 application with hangout service? To manage participants, rooms...

I found bundles for Google API or oAuth Google, but not for Hangout.

Thanks.

Comment: Perfect situation to write a bundle yourself, right?

Comment: I don't think there is a public API for what you're trying to do: https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/ - you can create apps to be part of hangouts (using JavaScript) but not something to control them externally.